# How to debug in Xtext with log4j?

Tags: log4j, xtext

How do I emit debug messages from within Xtext Java code?  I am using synthetic terminals, so ANTLRWorks will not suffice to debug my grammar.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with Xtext 2.10 and Eclipse 4.3.2 (Kepler).  In your main Eclipse Xtext project org.example.mydsl, edit build.properties and make sure you have

```
additional.bundles = ...,\
                     org.eclipse.xtext.logging,\
                     org.apache.commons.logging,\
                     org.apache.log4j,\
                     ...
```

In my project, org.eclipse.xtext.logging was missing.

In your Java code, use "error" priority; "info" and "debug" will be suppressed.

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

    Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class).error("My message");
```

Make sure to include "-consoleLog" in 
Run/Run Configurations.../XtextRuntime/Arguments/Program arguments.

The logged messages will appear in the XtextRuntime console of the parent instance, as well as in the Error Log view of the child instance.  You can also find them in the child instance from Help/About Eclipse Platform/Installation Details/Configuration/View Error Log.

Comment: Using xtend and making MyClass a xtend class the code `Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class).error("My message")` does not work. How do you log a message using xtend?